# How to add current slide number and fade effect to simple slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a very simple fullscreen website and I found this script in w3schools but I would like to know if it would be possible to add a fadein fadeout effect the slider.

Could someone find a way to display the current slide number as well?

Here goes a link to a fiddle I did.
https://jsfiddle.net/Lp1nv7wa/1/

If possible can you make the script verbose so I can try to understand the script. ( no knowledge of javascript)

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {showDivs(slideIndex += n);}
function currentDiv(n) {showDivs(slideIndex = n);}

function showDivs(n) {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("thumb");
if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
 x[i].style.display = "none";  
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
 dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" thumb_on", "");
}
x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
dots[slideIndex-1].className += " thumb_on";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript, there seems to be an error regarding your `dots` variable as you have no elements with `thumb` as a class name so I suggest commenting that out if it's not being used.

One way you can achieve a fade-in-fade-out effect is by using CSS and `opacity`. In your CSS, you can add these lines:

```
.mySlides{
  position: absolute;   /* puts all the slides on top of each other */
  top: 0; left: 0;      /* and positions them all at the top left   */
  transition: all 1s;   /* this animates the change in the css      */
                        /* the 1s stands for 1 second, you may      */
                        /* change that to any duration              */
}
```

For your javascript, you should change all of the `x[...].style.display` into ones that tweaks opacity.

```
function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.opacity = 0; //sets the opacity to 0
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = 1; //sets the opacity to 1

  document.getElementById("slideNumber").innerHTML = slideIndex; 
  //the previous line finds the element with an id of slideNumber
  //and sets its content to the current slide index
}
```

To complete the slide numbering, add this line where you want your slide number to appear.

```
<span id="slideNumber"></span>
```

Comment: Maybe something is missing me... but its not working the transition (fadein fade out). Here is a fiddle with the changes I did according to your instructions. https://jsfiddle.net/Lp1nv7wa/2/

Comment: woops! I used the wrong comment syntax for the CSS. I updated the code now. Note that CSS Transitions may work differently across browsers.